# L^2 space convolution inequality

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, convolution, integral-inequality

How do you use Young's Inequality, and all these convolution formulae to prove the following inequality 
$$||f*g||^2_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}\leq ||f*f||_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}||g*g||_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}$$
where 
$\mathbb{T}=[0,1)$ and $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried this. Since $f,g \in L^2 \Rightarrow f\ast g \in L^2$. Then use the plancherel theorem with the fact that $\hat{f\ast g}(n) = \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$.

Comment: We have not learned plancherel theorem yet, so I think there might be an alternative proof.